# Add custom feed to Wordpress: add_feed or do_feed

Tags: php, wordpress, feed

I have an existing custom feed using do_feed_* but I see there is an undocumented (and existing since 2.1) *_add_feed.  Is one better than the other?

I have do_feed_* working but since I upgraded to 3.0 last week, any URL with "&author=" in it redirects to the root site page.  Take it out and it loads the page fine (but of course does not show the proper author).  So, as I investigate, I wonder if *_add_feed might be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on an undocumented method in any API is more dangerous than figuring out how to properly use a documented method.

Answer (score 0):

[`add_feed`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed) is the best starting point and is now a documented part of WordPress. This function has been in WordPress since v2.1.

You should prefer adding your custom feed using `add_feed` over `do_feed_*`. An example of how to add your own custom RSS feed to WordPress is discussed on the WordPress Answers site: [Cannot get add_feed to work](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46467/cannot-get-add-feed-to-work).